# Is there an idiom which means one too many?

Tags: phrase-requests, idioms, idiom-requests

In my professional work, I often want to use a phrase which means:

> Here is an additional idea, but it may be one consideration too many and thus not useful / should be discarded.

For example in writing an analytical paper on foods we might consider their price and nutrition content. It could also be useful to look at their weights, but perhaps this is 'one too many' factors and overcomplicating things.

It feels like the phrase could be similar to 'too many cooks spoil the broth.'

I know I could just spell it out as above, but it'd be nice to have a quick and clear way to get the idea across (plus I'm curious if something like it exists).

Comment: In the context of food, 'overkill' might not be >le mot juste,<

Comment: "Less is more", "Goldilocks zone", "over-egging the pudding" are some expressions that come to mind. How formal a register are you interested in?

Comment: Those are great! I think I could use "less is more" and "Goldilocks zone" for sure, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call it **a bridge too far.** [The Free Dictionary defines it as:](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+bridge+too+far)

> An act or plan whose ambition overreaches its capability, resulting in or potentially leading to difficulty or failure

Answer (score 0):

This is a British idiom which says:

> ***carry/take coals to Newcastle***
> idiom UK
>
> to supply something to a place or person that already has a lot of that particular thing:
> Exporting pine to Scandinavia seems like ***carrying coals to Newcastle***. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/topics/size-and-quantity/too-much-and-unnecessary/))